# how to run a stream in different thread in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Future<bool> checkConnection() async {
  var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());

  bool connOk = false;

  if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
    bool ii = await checkConnectionWithUrl();
    if (ii == true) {
      connOk = true;
    }
  } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
    bool ii = await checkConnectionWithUrl();
    if (ii == true) {
      connOk = true;
    }
  } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.ethernet) {
    bool ii = await checkConnectionWithUrl();
    if (ii == true) {
      connOk = true;
    }
  } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.bluetooth) {
    bool ii = await checkConnectionWithUrl();
    if (ii == true) {
      connOk = true;
    }
  } else {
    connOk = false;
  }

  return connOk;
}

Future<bool> checkConnectionWithUrl() async {
  bool response = false;
  while (true) {
    var checkin = await client.get(Uri.https('www.google.com', '/'));
    if (checkin.statusCode == 200) {
      response = true;
      break;
    } else {
      sleep(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    }
  }
  return response;
}
```

```
Stream checkStream() async* {
  dynamic result = false;
  while (true) {
    try {
      result = await checkConnection();
    } catch (error) {
      result = false;
    } finally {
      yield result;
    }
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  }
}
```

I am making a app. And I want to learn multi threading in dart. The above function what it will do is it look  for wifi state every second and update the Ui. But when I run the function it will drop frams in ui. So I what to run it in a diffrent thread. can i do it.

---My main goal ---
I want to run this function in a different thread how do I do it

Comment: Your problem is that you are using `sleep`: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.5/dart-io/sleep.html which will halt all code from being executed. You can replace that `sleep` call with `await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));` which will allow other events to be executed while waiting.

Comment: Another thing to notice is that it seems rather unnecessary to download the Google homepage for checking if you are online. You are essentially downloading 42.7 KB just to check if the return code are 200 and then throw away the data.

Comment: is there any way to check if i am online that i can use in the code

Comment: I am not doing Flutter development but I would look at packages like these: https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus . Do note, that it does not guarantee internet connection to the site you want to contact since it only asks the OS if there are internet connection in general. The only way to know for sure you can connect to a specific site, is to try connect to that site.